# Fullcalendar, scheduler, and event start

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar and scheduler plugin, with a timelineMonth view.
Events are coming from a php file, and they are rendered well. Now, I'd like some of these events to have a "fixed" start : user is allowed to drag the end of the event, but isn't allowed to move the start.

Is there a way to do this ?

EDIT : I made a fiddle :
[FullCalendarFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johweb/p74zf5ke/38/)

Events have an editable property :

```
   eventDurationEditable: true
```

As you can see, there's an event. You can modify start and end, by dragging them with your mouse. I'd like "start" not to be editable, only end.
Is it possible ?

ps : sorry guys for previous bad posting, I'm also learning to use stackoverflow...

Comment: Sorry mate, without presenting any code no-one will be able to support you here.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventStartEditable may help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [eventResize](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventResize) event.

The relevant part is here:

> `delta` is a Duration Object that represents the amount of time the
>   event’s end was extended by.

You can therefore detect when the event's start is being modified when `delta` is `undefined`.

```
eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    if (typeof delta == 'undefined'){
        revertFunc();
    }
}
```

Check the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p74zf5ke/54/).

Comment: I found another way to do this, but yours is smarter !
Mine is to use eventAllow and compare event.start (before resize) and draggedEvent.start. Both are working fine. Thanks a lot !